# Translating a PHP function that converts seconds to human readable string

Tags: php, string, localization

[In this website](http://csl.sublevel3.org/php-secs-to-human-text/) I've found a function to convert seconds in an human readable format, like this:

> 3 weeks, 2 days, 1 hour, 27 minutes, 52 seconds

I want to translate it in italian, so I just translated array keys. The function now is this

```
function secondsToHumanReadable($secs) {

$units = array(
'settimane' => 604800,
'giorni'    =>  86400,
'ore'       =>   3600,
'minuti'    =>     60,
'secondi'   =>      1
);

foreach ( $units as &$unit ) {
    $quot  = intval($secs / $unit);
    $secs -= $quot * $unit;
    $unit  = $quot;
}

return $units;
}
```

It works pretty well, but there's a little problem: in english all the plurals ends with one letter less, but unfortunately in italian it's not the same, as you can see below.

```
English             Italian    
- weeks, week       - settimane, settimana
- days, day         - giorni, giorno
- hours, hour       - ore, ora
- minutes, minute   - minuti, minuto
- seconds, second   - secondi, secondo
```

I want to find a solution to print singular keys when the values are == 1.

I was thinking that I could merge the array with another array that have singular keys, using [array_combine()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php).

```
$singular_units = array(
'settimana',
'giorno',
'ora',
'minuto',
'secondo'
);

print_r(array_combine( $singular_units, $units ));

/* print_r:
Array
(
    [settimana] => 604800
    [giorno] => 86400
    [ora] => 3600
    [minuto] => 60
    [secondo] => 1
)
*/
```

The array above is what I need, but I'm not able to use it, since I just cannot use another `foreach`.

```
$seconds = 12345*60; // just an example
$units = secondsToHumanReadable($seconds);              
$time_string = '';
foreach ($units as $u => $v)
    if (!empty($v))
        $time_string.= $v.' '.$u.', ';
echo substr($time_string, 0, -2);
// 1 settimane, 1 giorni, 13 ore, 45 minuti
// this echo is not correct :( is expected to be like this:
// 1 settimana, 1 giorno, 13 ore, 45 minuti
```

How could I implement the singular words?

Any help is **really** appreciated! Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement them any way you like, IMHO preferably something not like the current solution which lacks clarity and readability (at least that's how the local-var-mutation-with-refs-and-variable-ping-pong looks like to me).

Just one possible solution:

```
$input = 12345 * 60;

$units = array(
    604800 => array('settimana', 'settimane'),
    86400 => array('giorno', 'giorni'),
    // etc
);

$result = array();
foreach($units as $divisor => $unitName) {
    $units = intval($input / $divisor);
    if ($units) {
        $input %= $divisor;
        $name = $units == 1 ? $unitName[0] : $unitName[1];
        $result[] = "$units $name";
    }
}

echo implode(', ', $result);
```

**[See it in action](http://ideone.com/HOBxC)**.

Answer (score 0):

Your probably want something like this?

```
function secondsToHumanReadable($secs) {

    $units = array(
    'settimane' => 604800,
    'giorni'    =>  86400,
    'ore'       =>   3600,
    'minuti'    =>     60,
    'secondi'   =>      1
    );

    foreach ( $units as $key => &$unit ) {

        $this_unit  = intval($secs / $unit);

        $secs -= $this_unit * $unit;

        if($this_unit == 1):    
            switch($key):
                case "settimane":
                    $this_key = "settimana";
                break;
                case "giorni":
                    $this_key = "giorno";
                break;
                case "ore":
                    $this_key = "ora";
                break;
                case "minuti":
                    $this_key = "minuto";
                break;
                case "secondi":
                    $this_key = "secondo";
                break;
            endswitch;
        else:
            $this_key = $key;
        endif;


        $results[$this_key] = $this_unit;
    }

    return $results;
}
```

This will return the full array, not your initial one...with results...

Answer (score 0):

Was also going to mention that some frameworks have Inflector classes which will determine the plural/singular version of a word, however I am not sure if they support languages such as Italian, but it may be worth a look. Personally I use CakePHP Inflector as it is a stand alone lib and I didn't need to bring in any other files.

CakePHP Inflector class
http://api.cakephp.org/class/inflector

Doctrine Inflector: http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/common/2.0/doctrine/common/util/inflector.html

Comment: Looks very interesting :) but unfortunately is only for english language